# Replacing the text by using jQuery script in shopify platform on the product page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, shopify, liquid

Please help me out I'm a beginner in the Shopify platform and don't understand how to add my script to Shopify files.
Please help me with where and in which file should I place the code to replace the text on the product page. I need to change the Price text with M.R.P see the screenshot for reference: https://prnt.sc/xFWR-QIpVkPr

Here is the product page URL: https://example.com/products/exfoliating-body-scrub-polisher-with-coffee-grape-seed-oil

See the code that I have used for scripting to replace, the HTML below is from the product page. I'm a little confused that the js library functions $ and jQuery both don't work in Shopify. Please help and give me the best solution to do this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-block product-block--price .variant__label').text('M.R.P');
});
```

```html
<div data-product-blocks="">
    <div class="product-block product-block--price">
        <label class="variant__label" for="ProductPrice-template--15540147159204__main">
            Price
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

the text with mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product-block--price label').text('M.R.P');
});
```

With js

```
document.querySelector('.product-block--price label').innerHTML = "M.R.P"
```

Comment: Hi @medou boushab, in shopify the $ or jQuery not working see the error on consol: https://prnt.sc/gXYzf5-JU0uH

Comment: where do you want to execute your code? if in the dev tools, you can use vanilla js

Comment: can you help me please in which file should I put the code so that it will execute on the frontend.